# Group by from the elements of array in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table which has two columns. The table has the following schema

```
column_name ---> type
student_id  ---> int
subjects    ---> array<string>
```

The sample data is:

```
student_id  --->  subjects
10          --->  [Math, Science]
20          --->  [Math, English]
30          --->  [English, French]
```

I want to group by the individual subject that is I want to count the number of subjects that all the students have taken. So my expected result is

```
Math     ---> 2
Science  ---> 1
English  ---> 2
French   ---> 1
```

I have heard about `unnest` an array, but not able to get this result.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to [`unnest`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```
select subject, count(*)
from t cross join
     unnest(subjects) as u(subject)
group by subject;
```

Comment: Thanks. The above query is giving me the expected result. It would be great if you can please edit your answer with bit of explanation of the above query. The syntax of the query is not so intuitive and hence asking for the explanation.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary see `unnest` at Presto documentation: https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest for more information.